# Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFC064FE58D (user32.dll) in Partical.exe: 0xC000041D: An unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback

Tags: c++, sdl

I have this SDL application called Partical. I am currently trying to call the function `SDL_CreateWindow` but I get an exception thrown in visual studio: Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFC064FE58D (user32.dll) in Partical.exe: 0xC000041D: An unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback. Here is the code for the application so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <SDL.h>
#undef main
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //SDL_SetMainReady();
    //SDL_SetError(SDL_ENABLE);
    const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 800;
    const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;
    
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0)
    {
        cout << "SDL initialization failed. SDL Error: " << SDL_GetError();
    }
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    window  = SDL_CreateWindow("Particle Fire Explosion", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0);

    
    if (window == NULL) {
        SDL_Quit();
        cout << "could not create window" << SDL_GetError() << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    return 0;
}
```

Checkout my GitHub for the project structure https://github.com/jasperhale342/Partical

From the release page on GitHub for sdl (https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/releases/tag/release-2.28.1), I downloaded SDL2-devel-2.28.1-mingw.zip
and extracted the header and library files from the x86_64-w64-mingw32 directory to a folder in my project called `Dependencies`.

To configure my Partical project, I first opened the properties menu and set the configuration to `All Configurations` and Platform to `x64`. To use the SDL header and library files in visual studio, I did the following:

Under Project->Properties->VC++ Directories->Include Directories, I added to the list where the sdl header files are located

Under Project->Properties->VC++ Directories->Library Directories, I added to the list where the sdl library files are located

under Project->Properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories, I added to the list where the sdl header files are located

under Project->Properties->C/C++->Code Generation, I changed runtime Library to Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)

under Project->Properties->Linker->General-> Additional Library Directories, I added to the list where the sdl library files are located

under Project->Properties->Linker ->input, I added the following files as Additional Dependencies:

```
libSDL2.a
libSDL2.dll.a
libSDL2_test.a
libSDL2main.a
opengl32.lib
user32.lib
gdi32.lib
Winmm.lib
SetupAPI.lib
Imm32.lib
Version.lib
kernel32.lib
winspool.lib
comdlg32.lib
advapi32.lib
shell32.lib
ole32.lib
oleaut32.lib
uuid.lib
odbc32.lib
odbccp32.lib
ntdll.lib
```

(I understand some of these are probably unnecessary but I just really want a window to pop-up)

I am using visual studio 2019 and compiling using x64 libraries. When I click on continue in the program, after the exception has been thrown, I get a new exception: Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFC064FE58D (user32.dll) in Partical.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000E79000F48.

Comment: You downloaded the MinGW version of SDL but you are using Visual Studio. That doesn't make sense. If both the statements are correct then it's not surprising that it isn't working, If you are using Visual Studio then you should have downloaded `SDL2-devel-2.28.1-VC.zip`

Comment: Yup that was it. Thank you